# Not able print html tags in Codeingiter 4

Tags: php, ckeditor5, codeigniter-4

I am using **CKEDITOR 5** to get input and store it into database, but when i try to output it ***prints html tags as raw text*** rather than displaying as html elements.
[image: The output]

```
<div class="container">
<?php foreach ($blog as $key => $post) : ?>
    <h1><?= $post['blog_title'] ?></h1>
    <div id="blog_content">
        <?= $post['blog_body'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You can try replacing $post['blog_body'] to htmlspecialchars($post['blog_body']) this should work and will echo your html.

Let me know it works or not.

Comment: Thanks @DipakMewada. The htmlspecialchars is not working... But the htmlspecialchars_decode() works. Thanks for helping to remember these function in php

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution. Use `htmlspecialchars_decode($variable,  ENT_HTML5)`.
This will print it in HTML5 format.

[image: Solved]

```
<div class="container">
<?php foreach ($blog as $key => $post) : ?>
    <h1><?= $post['blog_title'] ?></h1>
    <div id="blog_content">
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($post['blog_body'], ENT_HTML5) ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks @Dipak Mewada for helping out..